# type_info attempt to reference deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm attempting to store a collection of objects (all inherit from the base `acorn::Component`).
However, in my `AddComponent` function, I keep getting this error:

`error C2280: 'type_info::type_info(const type_info &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function`

I'm not sure why I am getting this error, as I do not have any deleted functions in either my `Component` classes or the class that stores all `Component` objects.

Here is the function that is giving me problems. It should add the `Component` to the map:

```
        template<typename T>
        void AddComponent(T* component)
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            SDL_Log("acorn::Entity::AddComponent called!");
#endif
            std::pair<std::type_index, acorn::Component*> myPair = std::make_pair(typeid(T), component);
            mComponentMap.insert(myPair);
        }
```

And here are the component classes:

```
namespace acorn
{
    struct Component
    {
    };

    struct PositionComponent : public acorn::Component
    {
        SDL_Rect positionRect;
        float x;
        float y;
        uint32_t ID;

        PositionComponent() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f), ID(0)
        {

        }
    };

    struct VelocityComponent : public acorn::Component
    {
        float xVel;
        float yVel;
        uint32_t ID;

        VelocityComponent() : xVel(0.0f), yVel(0.0f), ID(1)
        {

        }
    };

    struct SpriteComponent : public acorn::Component
    {
        SDL_Rect spriteRect;
        SDL_Texture* sprite;
        uint32_t ID;

        SpriteComponent() : ID(0)
        {
            spriteRect.x = 0;
            spriteRect.y = 0;
            spriteRect.h = 32;
            spriteRect.w = 32;

            sprite = nullptr;
        }
    };
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that this has something to do with structs, but I can not find anything that confirms this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make_pair` won't work with non-copyable types, since it creates a new pair prvalue.

Replace

```
std::pair<std::type_index, acorn::Component*> myPair = std::make_pair(typeid(T), component);
```

with

```
std::pair<std::type_index, acorn::Component*> myPair(typeid(T), component);
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Shouldn't the copy and move constructors be generated automatically, since I did not define them myself?

Comment: @Acorn: the type info type (the type of the expression `typeid(T)`) is not copyable, so the pair copy constructors are deleted.